# Understanding Tableau File Types better

Tags: tableau-api

I have done a lot of research on the file types of tableau but I would still like to know more about some file extensions

1. What is the relation between twbx and tdsx?
2. Is twbx file : twb + tde file OR twb+tde+tds file ?
3. What would be the main difference between tds and tdsx file ?
4. How to use a tps(preferences) file in tableau workbook?
5. can all the file extensions be used on server or only some ?

Comment: I believe all these questions can be answered by having a look in the tableau knowledge base. As an example you could start here for an explanation of TDS files: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/export_connection.html

Comment: I dont get the exact relations from those links.I'm trying to figure out how these files are related to each other

Answer (score 2):

1. twbx contains the workbook including a copy of all the data that you connected your workbook to, while a tdsx contains connection information to remote data sources (Server IPs, tables, etc) as well as any local data that somebody else wouldn't have access to otherwise (eg. an Excel file on your computer). No dashboards are involved. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/export_connection.html
2. A twbx is a twb with a tde file if you want. Remote and local data is stored within your workbook so that other people can access it https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_savework_packagedworkbooks.html
3. a tds only includes references to data sources but no actual data, so if you connect to a local excel file and it is not accessible via a network, a colleague of yours won't be able to use this file to get the data. A tdsx includes these datasets so you can share it. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/export_connection.html
4. A tps contains custom colour palettes, how you can use it can be found here: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_create_custom_colors.html
5. Generally all files that you can connect to with Tableau Desktop can be accessed via the server (assuming that the server can access them, ie. the files or sources are on the network). You might however be required to install additional drivers on the server to access for example SAP BW. These drivers are not contained in the default installation.